# How can I limit incoming/outgoing connection speeds based off IPs?

Tags: linux, bandwidth, tc, rate-limiting

I want to limit the speed each IP can download/upload files for every application on my server to 1Mb/s

Example IP 192.168.0.1 is downloading at sustained 900Kb/s through FTP server if the IP then attempts to download files through our webserver it would be able to download at 100Kb/s maximum until the FTP transfer is complete.

If another IP 192.168.0.2 wanted to download it too would have a maximum of 1Mb/s totalling 2Mb/s if they both where downloading/uploading

Comment: You will want to search this site for the commands and terms `tc` which is the tool to modify traffic shaping in Linux.  Also `HTB`, `rate limit`.  The reason I am not putting this in the answer field is that there are a million ways to do this and you should research which one fits your setup best and is easiest for you to implement.  There are many examples on this site and also on github.  In google, use "site:github.com tc htb rate limit"  as a query to find some of the working examples.   Remember to give your own management IP's and or the SSH port unlimited speed.